# python requests freeze program

Tags: python, python-requests, mp4, http-status-codes

I tried to use request to get status code from a web page but there is no output and the program stop at the request.get

my code

```
if requests.get("https://storage.googleapis.com/linear-theater-254209.appspot.com/v5.4animu.me/Hunter-x-Hunter/Hunter-x-Hunter-Episode-1-1080p.mp4").status_code == 200:
  print("link is working")
else:
  print("link is not working")
```

the code worked on another machine

I think it's downloading the video but I just want the status code

I didn't download files using requests before so IDK about that

Edit:
it also works on Collaboratory
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yECaNKQNsyDUuGhBfcEa2OhDUUqqeg_q

Comment: What's the error that this code produces? Or does it just stop?

Comment: it just stop
it didn't give me any error @definaly

Comment: i always do something like this but this time it stopped

maybe because it's direct link to video and have .mp4 extension

Comment: @definaly the code don't exit just freeze

Comment: I don't understand how you can say "I didn't download file using requests before" and "the code worked on another machine".  If it worked on another machine, then you HAVE downloaded files using requests before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `requests.head()` to get the headers like this :

```
    import requests

    if requests.head("https://storage.googleapis.com/linear-theater-254209.appspot.com/v5.4animu.me/Hunter-x-Hunter/Hunter-x-Hunter-Episode-1-1080p.mp4").status_code == 200:
      print("link is working")
    else:
      print("link is not working")
```

`requests.get()` will download the requested URL and since the file you requested here is not small it may take some time. if you want to check the headers and status code it's better to use `requests.head()` instead.